# Powershell Script isn't returning anything (Running on MAC OS)

Tags: macos, powershell, operating-system

I've been messing with this powershell script (i installed powershell on my mac OS) I also modified the code a bit in the first line.

I am not getting any errors, just nothing happens.

```
$folder = “/Users/mbp/Desktop/nier_unpacked_2_extracted“
$files = gci -recurse $folder | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
$fileContents = $files | foreach { gc -encoding utf8 $_.fullname }
$lines = $fileContents | foreach { if ($_ -match "^JP: (.*)$") { $matches[1] } }
$chars = $lines | foreach { $_.ToCharArray() }
$groups = $chars | group-object
$totals = $groups | sort-object -desc -property count
```

Basically outputting japanese text characters and how often they show up.

This is the original code(before modification):

```
$folder = "F:\nier_unpacked_2_extracted"
$files = gci -recurse $folder | where { ! $_.PSIsContainer }
$fileContents = $files | foreach { gc -encoding utf8 $_.fullname }
$lines = $fileContents | foreach { if ($_ -match "^JP: (.*)$") { $matches[1] } }
$chars = $lines | foreach { $_.ToCharArray() }
$groups = $chars | group-object
$totals = $groups | sort-object -desc -property count
```

Here is the link to the resource i got the code from if that helps: https://dev.to/nyctef/extracting-game-text-from-nier-automata-1gm0

I'm not sure why nothing is returning unfortunately.

Comment: Any errors? What do you try to achieve (apart from messing around)? What do you expect? What do you actually get? See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'll include a screenshot of what im expecting. The link gives the code and the output. I also don't get any errors, just nothing happens.

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out those errors, I updated the post with more information

Comment: So far I can determine, the script is not supposed to return anything. The result is in `$totals`. Meaning, if you type `$totals<Enter>` you should see the results. If not, try `$groups<Enter>` upto `$files<Enter>`

Comment: $totals worked! The only issue is I am getting numbers instead of japanese characters. I will edit this post with the results I am getting.

Comment: Ok that's what I will do, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PowerShell (as in most other programming languages), `$totals = ...` means that you assign the result of the expression at the right side is assigned to the variable (`$totals`) at the left side.
To display the contents of the variable (`$totals`), you might use the [`Write-Output $totals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7), [`Write-Host $totals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7), [`Out-Defualt $totals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/out-default?view=powershell-7), along with a lot of other output cmdlets.
Anyways, in PowerShell, it is generally not necessary to use a cmdlet in instances where the output is displayed by default. For example:

### `$totals` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Thanks I edited it and for the new question ill try to get everything cleaned up with the images, thanks!